# Use of "can" or "may" to imply possibility

Tags: modal-verbs

1."There can/may be many reasons for this".

2."It can/may rain tomorrow."

I thought that my concept is clear regarding difference between 'can' and 'may',but I get confused while using them in aforementioned lines.

Comment: Both *can* and *may* imply either *possibility* or *permission*, depending on the context.  *May* is generally more **polite** than *can*.  Otherwise this is basic grammar so please add more detail to your question, so we can understand what specifically you find confusing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define *possibility.*

*Can* means that something is *possible* in the sense that **it is able to occur**.

> It **can** get very dark at night.
>
> Ice cream **can** melt quickly in hot temperatures.

*May* means that something is *possible* in the sense that **there is a chance that it occurs**.

> It **may** get very dark, so bring a flashlight with you.
>
> The ice cream **may** melt quickly, so buy some napkins just in case.

---

Now, let's analyse your sentences.

> There **can** be many reasons for workers being late, including traffic and weather conditions.
>
> There **may** be many reasons for workers being late, since the subways are closed and the streets are covered in snow.

The first option makes a general statement. Workers are late for many reasons, and these reasons **are able to occur**. The second option is not definitive. Since most of the transportation is not running, there **is a chance that** workers will be late because of these reasons.

> It **can** rain a lot in mountainous regions because humid air is forced upwards producing clouds.
>
> It **may** rain a lot tomorrow, so bring your umbrella to work.

The first option makes a general statement. Rain **is able to occur** in mountainous regions because of the movement of humid air. The second option is not definitive. Since there may be weather patterns showing rain the next day, **there is a chance** that it will rain.